# oracle forms loop through a block before or after insert

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

I am trying to insert values of A block into a table in oracle forms after insert like this

```
GO_BLOCK ('LCL_SP_DTL');
   LAST_RECORD;
   LV_N_LAST_REC := :SYSTEM.TRIGGER_RECORD;
   FIRST_RECORD;
   LV_N_FST_REC := :SYSTEM.TRIGGER_RECORD;

   FOR I IN LV_N_FST_REC .. LV_N_LAST_REC
   LOOP
      INSERT INTO LEDGER(LDATE, LTYPE, DESCRIPTION, DEBIT, CREDIT, SID,VID)
           VALUES (:LCLSP_MST.REC_DATE, 'Local Sale', DES, 0, AMOUNT, LS_ID,'LS-' || :LCLSP_MST.REC_ID);
      NEXT_RECORD;
   END LOOP;
```

But its gving me error not working properly .Plz give any suggestion to insert values in `LEDGER` on runtime

Comment: What error? What does "not working properly" mean?

Comment: mean its not inserting values

Comment: Please [edit] your question with the **exact** error message. Error messages are very important. You should always include them verbatim when you get one (after having read it very carefully and having searched on the Internet for similar problems to yours).

Comment: have you issued a commit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `:SYSTEM.TRIGGER_RECORD`, which is the record number where your code originated. It doesn't change just because you've navigated to another record. In other words, your `LV_N_LAST_REC` and `LV_N_FST_REC` will be set to the same value.

You *could* use `:SYSTEM.CURRENT_RECORD` I think, but a better solution is the traditional forms record loop:

```
GO_BLOCK ('LCL_SP_DTL');
FIRST_RECORD;
LOOP
  INSERT INTO LEDGER(LDATE, LTYPE, DESCRIPTION, DEBIT, CREDIT, SID,VID)
       VALUES (:LCLSP_MST.REC_DATE, 'Local Sale', DES, 0, AMOUNT, LS_ID
              ,'LS-' || :LCLSP_MST.REC_ID);
  EXIT WHEN :SYSTEM.LAST_RECORD = 'TRUE';
  NEXT_RECORD;
END LOOP;
```